# Embedding fonts into Adobe AIR application

Tags: css, fonts, air

Here's another issue with HTML-based Adobe Air application I am developing at the moment. 
The question is whether I can embed custom font into my application. If it is possible, then, how do I do this?

I have my custom font file in app:/fonts directory, Firefox displays text correctly using this font when I'm viewing the page in it. But when I start AIR application everything is broken - I see only default font.

I've been searching all over the Internet, but found only some outdated links on how to embed font in CSS, though it works only for IE.

Thanks in advance, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding fonts in this way is not currently supported. Any fonts used must be installed on the user's computer.

Comment: Anyway, cufon helped me much with this trouble. The only curious detail with cufon is that you have to make an element visible before you apply cufon to it